# How do I reset RHEL6 to autocreate home directory upon login?

Tags: rhel, authentication, ldap

I am using a RHEL6 host that is set up using LDAP for authenication. Upon first login it is supposed to create the home directory for the user (e.g. `/home/gisle` where *gisle* is my login username).  I have not configured this host myself.

I goofed up. I am supposed to connect from another host (*staff.example.com*) in the cluster using the following command:

```
ssh gisle@remote.example.com
```

I've done this on dozen of identically configured hosts, and it works.

However, this time I typed:

```
ssh remote.example.com
```

I was not prompted for a username, but username *gisle* was obviously assumed. When I typed in the password (using the same password as I use to authenticate on *staff.example.com*), I was authenticated with LDAP and logged in, but no home directory was created on this inital login (instead my account was set up with my home directory set to the home directory path picked up from the machine I was coming from - i.e. `/home/staff/g/gisle`).

Logging out and logging in again (with `ssh gisle@remote.example.com`) does not fix the problem. The notion about the "wrong" home directory persists.

I have the same username (gisle) on both systemes.  My home directory on *staff.example.com* is `/home/staff/g/gisle`.  This directory does not exist on *remote.example.com* - nor is it supposed to exist.

Here is the result of logging in on the remote now:

```
$ ssh gisle@remote.example.com
Last login Sun Jan 19 16:22:40 2014 from staff.example.com
Could not chdir to home directory /home/staff/g/gisle
$ whoami
gisle
$ echo $HOME
/home/staff/g/gisle
$ pwd
/
```

I need to "reset" the status of my account so that the RHEL6 host forget all about me logging in, believe I am logging in for the first time, and automatically create the home directory. I have root access on *remote.example.com*, but do not know what to do.

Comment: What you're describing makes no sense, please [edit] your question and clarify. i) Log in to the remote with `ssh username@example.com` and run `whoami`, `echo $HOME` and `pwd` ii) do you have the same username on both systems? If you do your `$HOME` will have the same path on both systems. iii) do you have root access to the remote system?

Comment: @terdon, I've edited the question to address your comment.  I am now using my real username on both systems in a  hope that this makes the question clearer.

Comment: OK, thanks, that's much clearer, the key points hre are LDAP and the fact that you _do_ have the same username. Do you have root access to all the machines involved?

Comment: @terdon, no - only on *remote.example.com* (this is an experimental virtual host set up for me specifically).  I am not root on *staff.example.com*.

Comment: I have no experience with LDAP but what does `grep gisle /etc/passwd`return on the remote system? Can't you just edit that file and set your `$HOME` there?

Comment: @terdon that `grep` wont work with LDAP. The equivalent that would is `getent passwd gisle`, which goes through nsswitch, and will work with whatever authentication backend is used.

Comment: Here's a big clue guys: http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=ldap&f=2. Notice the pam module that auto creates the user's home dir. in this tutorial? This is likely the source of the issue. I don't have time to debug this though I really want to, have to step out w/ family for most of the rest of today. Be back later though.

Comment: @slm I don't agree that it's the source. Everything I see points to a misconfigured server. The server should not be picking up the home directory path from the connecting client. The fact that it is sounds like someone pointed this server at the wrong authentication backend.

Comment: @Patrick - fair enough. It's a lead. At a minimum it shows us the direction to explore wrt where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me this sounds like the server has been misconfigured.

As you stated, the system automatically picked up your username (gisle) upon logging in. This is the **only** thing that prefixing your username with an '@' does. Meaning, on all the following commands, if the user you are runnning as is 'gisle', they are *exactly* equivalent.

```
ssh gisle@remote.example.com
ssh -l gisle remote.example.com
ssh remote.example.com
```

Your question indicates that your work environment has 2 sets of systems, one that uses `/home/staff/g/gisle`, and one that uses `/home/gisle`. This obviously means you have 2 authentication backends (LDAP, NIS, etc). The behavior you are seeing would indicate that the system you are logging into is configured to use the wrong authentication backend.
If you were to change your password on the systems which use `/home/staff/g/gisle`, I'd bet you'd find your password changed on this system as well.

Meaning this is not an issue on your part. The solution here is to contact the administrator of the system and request they fix it.

Comment: "If you were to change your password on the systems which use /home/staff/g/gisle, I'd bet you'd find your password changed on this system as well." Sure.  That is what LDAP authentication is supposed to do.  My entry in `/etc/passwd` on the remote is simply `+gisle` (and nothing more). I am told that this means that authentication should be done using LDAP against my account on *staff.example.com*.  However, if first time login to the remote is done using `ssh gisle@remote.example.com`, this problem does *not* happen.  I guess I need to talk to the administrator to esolve this.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr Yes, but it sounds like you have 2 separate authentication systems. Your authentication system is not just responsible for your password, it's responsible for your account info, including your home directory. Meaning one system contains `/home/staff/g/gisle` and the other contains `/home/gisle`. So if you change your password on the `/home/staff/g/gisle` system, anything with `/home/gisle` should use your old password. While it is technically possible for some sort of directory mapping to be going on, I would not consider it likely.

Comment: You're right.  This particular server *is* misconfigured (it was missing `homedir_override` from its cfengine policy).  That I forgot to give my username when logging in the first time was a coincidence.  My initial login should have worked if the configuration had been correct.